# With the following preamble the identation works fine but there is no distance added between the footnote number and the footnote text

Tags: footnotes

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{12pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1em][r]{\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=nominum, title=Index nominum, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=rerum, title=Index rerum, columns=2]
\pretolerance=100
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
% And in the paragraphed footnotes, I'd like no colon too:
\def\parafootfmt#1#2#3{%
  \normal@pars
  \parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  {\bf\printlines#1|}%
  {\select@lemmafont#1|#2}~%
  #3\penalty-10 }
\makeatother
\let\Afootfmt\parafootfmt

%\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Afootnote{] #2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Bfootnote{] #2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\raggedbottom


\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \parbox{\LeftWidth}{\raggedleft\textbf{#1}\strut~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%


%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing

\newfontfamily{\H}[Scale=0.9]{Lucida Grande}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=5pt}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

Comment: What exactly about the `footmisc` package "does not work" with your preamble? Speaking for myself, I seem to have no problems getting the package's "hang" option to do what it's supposed to do. Remark: I did have to set the option `noeledmac` when loading the `ledmac` package in order to get the code to compile.

Comment: The package `ledmac` is utterly deprecated by now. If you insist on using it anyway, it should be loaded with the option `noeledmac`. Incidentally, might the "nothing happens when I typeset" problem be caused by the fact that the code you've posted does not actually do anything? In particular, the code doesn't contain a single `\footnote` command, and it's also missing the instruction `\end{document}`, which is needed to make the code compilable.

Comment: In order to understand what's going on in your code, it's important that you post an example that reproduces an instance of the code not working. Otherwise, it's pretty much impossible for us to diagnose the problem, let alone come up with a fix.